# How do I find out the data size of write request per day or per second in my Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I have Cassandra cluster with 10 nodes and 5 tables.
I want to know that how many bytes of data are stored on a specific table by write request per day (or per sec).

Is there any way to get it roughly using jmx or something?

I tried to use nodetool tablestats, but the output does not have any related informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

metrics reporting on cassandra uses Dropwizard metrics and there are a set of default counters. In the past , I've had a custom set up with Cassandra running on k8s where these metrics can be exported (and we sent that to Prometheus). JMX queries are permitted on these metrics. We had a metrics exporter that exported these exposed metrics to Prometheus

https://github.com/nabto/cassandra-prometheus

There are other deployment types which use other agents to export these metrics
https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.7/opsc/LCM/opscLCMconfigMetricsCollector.html

the default metrics are https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/metrics.html. Within this LiveDiskSpaceUsed (Disk space used by SSTables belonging to this table (in bytes)) may be of interest. You can store it on a time series database and then query this over time to get the delta

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a command that will give you this information out of the box.

You will need to implement monitoring using tools like [Metrics Collector for Apache Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra) (MCAC). MCAC is an open-source tool so it's free to use. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for introducing a good tool! I installed it successfully and it's working fine :)

Comment: That's really good to hear. Cheers!